# Declarative creation of an Overlay with ScrollStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

**TL,DR**; How can a [scroll strategy](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#ScrollStrategyOptions) be used when creating a [CdkConnectedOverlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#CdkConnectedOverlay) declaratively?

**Detail**; [CdkConnectedOverlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#CdkConnectedOverlay) is a Directive to facilitate declarative creation of an Overlay.

It provides [numerous](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#CdkConnectedOverlay) `@Input()` properties, most of which are intuitive. For example:

```
<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay
             cdkConnectedOverlayOpen="true"
             cdkConnectedOverlayOffsetX="0"
             cdkConnectedOverlayOffsetY="0">

    <span>I'm an overlay</span>
</ng-template>
```

One property defines a [scroll strategy](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#ScrollStrategyOptions):

```
@Input('cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy')
scrollStrategy: ScrollStrategy
```

> Strategy to be used when handling scroll events while the overlay is
>   open.

However it's not clear how to define a scroll strategy when creating an overlay declaratively.

The source code ([material2/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.ts](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.ts#L166)) provides a little insight:

```
  /** Strategy to be used when handling scroll events while the overlay is open. */
  @Input('cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy') scrollStrategy: ScrollStrategy =
      this._scrollStrategy();
```

Clearly, a strategy can be provided, but unlike other properties, it's assigned a value of `this._scrollStrategy();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's the optimal way to do it, but in order to help with a solution. This is what I did:

```
scrollStrategy: ScrollStrategy;

constructor (private sso: ScrollStrategyOptions) {
    this.scrollStrategy = sso.<select-your-strategy>();
}
```

And then on the view you just have to

```
<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay
             cdkConnectedOverlayOpen="true"
             cdkConnectedOverlayOffsetX="0"
             cdkConnectedOverlayOffsetY="0"
             [cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy]="scrollStrategy">
    <span>I'm an overlay</span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can involve the different scroll strategy via this.

@Input('cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy') scrollStrategy: ScrollStrategy = this.scrollStrategies.block();